# Question about Regression, Projection model, CEF, and Structural Model

Tags: regression, econometrics, causality

I want to clarify different concepts that seem kind of mixed in my head, name how the relationship between the linear regression model and the conditional expectation relate to notions of causality. My understanding/background comes from econometrics and reading Mostly Harmless Econometrics.

The first, given my understanding (assuming this logic is correct?)

We can think of the conditional expectation function (CEF) of Y given X, E[Y|X], as just a descriptive measure. This can be highly non-linear but using regression (by least squares) always yields a consistent and unbiased estimator of the linear projection model. The linear projection model then is the best linear approximation to the CEF (in a mean squared error sense), so we can think that the linear regression is a way to estimate the best linear approximation to the CEF, but the CEF interpretation is what we are usually looking for.

But now, if I want to say estimate a causal quantity, I need to assume a causal structural model. This is where I am a little confused, is the structural model defined in terms of the CEF, in other words, if the CEF can give a causal relationship (E[Y|X] = E[y|do(X)]), and if the conditions are met for this (backdoor criterion), then the linear regression is giving me a consistent estimate of the best linear approximation to the causal CEF? This seems to me to be the Angrist argument - the linear regression is causal when the CEF it estimates is causal.

Or does the CEF property have to be invoked at all? For example, I can define a Structural equation as $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \epsilon$, where $\beta_1$ is defined as the causal effect. But it could easily be the case that the *structural* error, $\epsilon$, is correlated with X.  The linear regression model is always a projection coefficient, so the linear regression model: $Y = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 X + \eta$ will always estimate $\alpha$ such that $cov(x,\eta)= 0$. but since the regression error is not equal to the structural error, then this will be inconsistent in respect to $\beta_1$ - in the population, the linear projection is not the same as the causal effect. But if I can satisfy the backdoor criterion (assume the only relevant omitted variable is Z), I can rewrite the structural model as
$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \beta_2 Z + \epsilon'$

where now, given my assumptions, $cov( \epsilon', X) = 0$,

in which case by estimating the following projection model:  $Y = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 X + \alpha_2 + \eta'$, I can obtain consistent estimates of $\beta_1$ with $\hat{\alpha_1}$

If these two different 'models' of getting the causal effect of x on y is correct, then are these both valid? or are they both connected/consistent with each other?

Comment: Without trying to dive into the details: You provide an example of a single structural equation. I think things wold be a lot clearer if you gave a full structural causal model.